# Workspace add-on not showing in Google Sheet when developed with one Google account (showing perfectly fine for other account)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm having trouble getting a Google Workspace add-on to show up in the right toolbar in Google Sheets – with *one* of my Google accounts. When I create a Google Apps Script project with the exact same code from another account, the add-on appears in Google Sheet as expected. Also, when I set the script up for Google Docs, it show up with both accounts.

As this problem seems to be connected with one of my Google accounts, I contacted Google support. They say that there is no problem with the permissions or anything like that on my account, and they also confirm that there is nothing wrong with my code, but that I have to ask about it in this forum. I hope someone here can point me in the right direction, as I have no idea what the problem might be.

Short background: I have been developing an Editor add-on for Google Sheet, and have started the process of publishing it (I have connected it to a GCP project and startet filling in all the forms there). Along the way, Google launched the Workspace approach to add-ons, with Cards etc., so I started a new project with the same account, to recreate the add-on as a Workspace add-on. I can't really see any reason the old app should affect the new one, but this is so weird that I won't rule anything out.

What I have done to debug this:

- I have created a new project with both accounts, with the exact same code (works with one, not the other). I have been using one browser for each account
- I have tried to run the failing project in yet another browser, signed in as the account with the problem, and it fails there too

The add-on code is simple and is only there to get the icon in the right toolbar (I know I'm supposed to return a card etc, but here I just want to see if the code is ran and to get the icon in the toolbar):

```
function onHomepage() {
  console.log('Here we are');
}
```

The manifest uses this as a common homepage for both Sheets and Docs:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Addon new version",
      "logoUrl": "https://bcassetcdn.com/social/949ya4wv84/preview.png",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomepage",
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "sheets": {},
    "docs": {}
  }
}
```

I install this as a test deployment, and then create a new Google Sheet or a new Google Docs.

Any suggestions on how to get to the buttom of this?

Comment: We don't mind solving all of your problems but we prefer to handle them one at a time. You pick which on you want first

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper. I would like the workspace add-on to show up as an icon in the toolbar in Google Sheets. :)

Comment: What type of ad on is it?

Comment: It's a Google Workspace add-on, enabled for Google Sheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an already reported issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170819044) that only some accounts experience. If you are experience the behaviour described in that report please indicate that you are also affected by it by starring this report.

Comment: Yes, this sounds exactly like what I'm experiencing, so I've starred it now. I have also gotten a reply from Google support that they have to open cases that might be related to my case, so it sounds like they are aware of this.

Comment: I just got word from Google support that I'm affected by two different bugs, that they hope to fix by early Q2. Thanks for pointing me in the direction of this issue, @mateo.

Comment: No worries, glad they confirmed this ! :D